# Get Column Position Based Off Search Text & Move

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am needing to always make sure that `name` is in Column C and `address` is in column D.  I use the below synatx to scan for the header text and determine the column position each header is in, but if the header text does not meet the mandatory position, what would be the syntax to move it to the correct position?

```
Sub SearchForText()
    Dim strSearch As String,  aCell As Range, strSearch1 As String
    Dim aCell1 As Range, namecolumn As Int, addresscolumn As Int

    strSearch = "Name"  

    Set aCell = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    GetColumnName(aCell.Column)
    namecolumn = GetColumnName()

    strSearch1 = "Address"

    Set aCell = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch1, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    GetColumnName(aCell1.Column)
    addresscolumn = GetColumnName()

    if namecolumn <> 3 THEN
        'How to copy column to be position 3?
    end if

    if addresscolumn <> 4 THEN
        'How to copy column to be position 4?
    end if
End Sub
Function GetColumnName(colNum As Integer) As String
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim name As String
    d = colNum
    name = ""
    Do While (d > 0)
        m = (d - 1) Mod 26
        name = Chr(65 + m) + name
        d = Int((d - m) / 26)
    Loop
    GetColumnName = name
End Function
```

Comment: In your code your comment is `'How to copy column to be position 4?` so I assume you want to move the entire column - not just the header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go by simply moving values, as follows:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim colIndex As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        CheckColumn .Rows(1), "Name", 3
        CheckColumn .Rows(1), "Address", 4
    End With
End Sub

Sub CheckColumn(rngHeaderRow As Range, colName As String, refColumnIndex As Long)
    Dim columnIndex As Long
    With rngHeaderRow.Parent
        If GetColumnIndex(rngHeaderRow, colName, columnIndex) Then If columnIndex <> refColumnIndex Then MoveValues .Columns(columnIndex), .Columns(refColumnIndex)
    End With
End Sub

Function GetColumnIndex(rngHeaderRow As Range, colName As String, columnIndex As Long) As Boolean
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = rngHeaderRow.Find(What:=colName, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        columnIndex = rng.Column
        GetColumnIndex = True
    End If
End Function

Sub MoveValues(colToMoveFrom As Range, colToMoveTo As Range)
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim maxSize As Long

    ResizeColumn colToMoveFrom
    ResizeColumn colToMoveTo
    maxSize = WorksheetFunction.Max(colToMoveFrom.Count, colToMoveTo.Count)
    With colToMoveFrom.Parent.UsedRange
        arr = Application.Transpose(colToMoveFrom.Resize(maxSize))
        colToMoveFrom.Resize(maxSize).Value = colToMoveTo.Resize(maxSize).Value
        colToMoveTo.Resize(maxSize).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End With
End Sub

Sub ResizeColumn(rng As Range)
    With rng.Parent
        Set rng = .Range(rng.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: a bit lengthy - but does the job as it should.

Comment: actually the code length is mainly due to a _certain_ degree of re usability and maintainability given it by splitting each task to specific Functions/Subs, each one of them being very short. I could propose a shorter one but it'd be a one-shot only code. Finally, you should compare its length to another functioning code...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need is this:-

```
With aCell
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Value = .Value
    .Value = ""
End With
```

Since your Find function found the "Name" in aCell, the above code copies from aCell to column 3 ("C") and deletes it where it was before. Note that a Cell is always defined as Cells([Row], [Column]). Numbers are preferred for the Column property but letters will also work.

BTW, don't bother to convert column numbers to column names because Excel only understands numbers and converts your names back to numbers.

```
Columns("AL").Column    ' returns the column number of column "AL"
Columns(155).Address     ' returns $EY:$EY
```